# Primefaces filter not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I want to use `filter` attribute for `<p:selectOneMenu>` which has a list of items of type Units which is an `Enum` class as shown below:

```
public enum Units {

      PERCENT, MILLIMETER, METER, NUMBER
}
```

When I use `filter` with `<p:selectOneMenu>`, nothing is filtered. I think it is because the list has items of type Units and I am comparing Strings in the filter. Should I use a converter for the Unit items to be converted to String before I can match them in the filter? If so, how should my converter be?

Comment: not sure, but take a  look at this example pf player convertor which is being used in primefacs showcase example ... http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/view/PlayerConverter.java

Comment: @Daniel - I know that example. It makes it easy if I have a class with getters and setters. But I have an Enum class whose items I pass to the `p:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: so you can use `PERCENT.name()` to have it as string and `Units.valueOf("some String")` to have it as enum back again...

Comment: @Daniel: the filter runs fully at client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is how I made it working. In the `<p:selectOneMenu>` I added an attribute `height="200"`. As per the code snippet [SelectOneMenu with filter not working with less than 10 elements](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4594), the filter only works if the height is set.

Comment: 3.5 should fix it with no height setting as well.

Comment: @CagatayCivici - Thanks, will do. Just posted an answer in case if anyone encounters a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your problem. The filter works only if the list of items has exceeded the default amount of visible items. This is really a bug in JavaScript responsible for creating the menu and initializing the filter. Your best bet is [reporting](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) it as a bug to PrimeFaces guys.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks! But is there a way in which I can make it working? Does a converter not solve the problem?